# I'm creating an AVD and i have trouble with emulator_arm.exe

Tags: android

My computer is using Window Xp so Android Wear Intel Atom is not an option. I tried to create an AVD using Android Wear ARM but somehow it takes so long. I adjusted RAM 1024, Internal storage 200MiB,VM Heap 64. Target Android 4.4W2. I can create an AVD but when i press Start it takes so long for the AVD to show up on screen. Can i do something to fix this?

Comment: bluestacks could be your alternative

Comment: I tried install bluestacks but when i run thinInstaller_native.exe it required bluestack appplayer and i dont know how to get it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe your PC is slow thats why AVD takes time to run. My previous PC took very much time to start AVD. It had 1GB RAM and a slow processor. Also, you can try  [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com)  to run your app. It is comparatively faster than AVD.

Comment: My PC is Pentium(R) dual core CPU E5300 2,6Ghz 2GB of RAM. Do u think my PC is incapable of launching AVD faster?

Comment: I installed the whole eclipse sdk package before and the AVD ran pretty smooth. But then i deleted the whole thing and installed it again and i had this trouble.

Comment: Then I think when you installed the Eclipse SDK, some files of the previous installation were still left behind. That is why it is slow. **PS -** Try Android Studio, its better and the official SDK for Android.